# Addition of series and float always returns n/a in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Basic exmaple

```
var cur_val = 0.0
cur_val:= cur_val + (close/close[1])
```

`cur_val` will be `n/a`, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using var saves a value and := sets it to another. At run time the statement (close/close[1]) returns na on the first bar, so the effective calculation that results is :

cur_val = 0.0 + na

var keeps the value and we set it to na

A way to avoid this is either remove var, or place cur_val:= cur_val + (close/close[1]) under the local scope of an if statement to assign a new value conditionally

Cheers!

Comment: Correct! This was such a headache for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and didn't get it...
Does not work (solution below):

```
myLow() => 
    result = low
    result := low < result[1] ? low : result[1] // just infinitely copies n/a
    result

mMyLow = myLow()

plot(mMyLow)
plotchar(mMyLow, title='myLow', char='')
```

Solution: detect n/a with funktion na() (n/a probably coming from the first bar)

```
putMyLow() => 
    result = low
    if not na(result[1])
        result := low < result[1] ? low : result[1]
    else
        low
    result

mMyLow = putMyLow()

plot(mMyLow)
plotchar(mMyLow, title='myLow', char='')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).